# audioOutput device is not setting through aws chime sdk js chooseAudioOutput

Tags: javascript, reactjs, aws-chime-sdk, amazon-chime

I'm getting device from useAudioOutputs() hook that is provider by amazon-chime-sdk-component-library-react and its populating the device but when i pass the deviceId to function chooseAudioOutput it ain't changing device

"amazon-chime-sdk-component-library-react": "^3.7.0",
"amazon-chime-sdk-js": "^3.18.2",

```js
try {
          const selectedAudioOutputDeviceInfo = audioOutputs.find(
            (device: any) => device?.deviceId === deviceId?.value,
          )
          const selectedDeviceId = selectedAudioOutputDeviceInfo?.deviceId
          console.log('selected sound', selectedAudioOutputDeviceInfo?.deviceId)
          await meetingSession.audioVideo.chooseAudioOutput(selectedDeviceId) 
        } catch (error) {
          console.log('error in changing speaker', error)
        }
```